# Merging PDF files per the first part of files names - how to automate?

Tags: vba, batch-file, pdf, merge, pdftk

I was able to revised a sample `VBA` code I found here to generate `PDF` files from an `excel` file. After this coding runs, the results is that I will have multiple `PDF` files with suffix `"-index.pdf"` - (e.g., `875458-indexl.pdf`) I can change the suffix to anything.

And I will extract another set of PDF files from a zip file that have the identical file name as `875458.pdf`.

At the end, in one folder, there will be multiple pairs of files as below.

```
875458.pdf
875458-index.pdf
875460.pdf
875460-index.pdf
954784.pdf
954784-index.pdf
```

My goal is to find a w

ay to merge each pair of files into one file.

The end result would be as below.

(Indexl file being the first pages)

```
875458.pdf 
875460.pdf
954784.pdf
```

I downloaded PDFtk, but I don't know exactly how script works, and even though I see some samples, I just don't get it...

If someone can kindly shows me the following, I would appreciate it greatly.

1) Which programs I should have installed
2) How to name the `batch` or `bash` file, and where to save the file
3) how to trigger the script to run

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the command to merge/join two pdf files with PDFtk [on this page](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/).

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%# in (*-index.pdf) do (
    set n=%%~n#
    set n=!n:~,-6!
    pdftk A=!n!.pdf B=%%# cat B A output C:\export\done\!n!.pdf
)
```

This will get every *-index.pdf and merge it with its respective *.pdf.

Comment: Great! But I have no idea now what to do with this.. But I will google and find out... But please feel free to let me know how to run this command line. I do have installed Pdftk pro just now... Thank you again for giving me a starting point!

Comment: @EunNamkung Just save it as a .bat file in the directory of the .pdf files and double-click to start. Make sure PDFtk is also located in either the directory or in \Windows\System32.

Comment: Thank you, but not working... Well, thank you for your time! Hopefully, I will get inspired and understand what I am not doing right!

Comment: @EunNamkung What specifically isn't working? Try opening the script via cmd to see what errors you get.

Comment: 1) I opened CMD window and drilled down to the folder I saved PDF files, the Bat file, and pdftk.exe file. 2) I typed bat file name which is merge2 3) then this comes up - C:\merge>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion, but the files are not merged.

Comment: @EunNamkung Only the first line comes up? I don't have PDFtk installed, but it seems "PDFtk Server" is the command line tool. I am not sure if you have command line functionality without it. The script is so far working for me, at least the lines are put out correctly. The problem must be with the `pdftk` line. Try merging a single pair manually via command line and see if you get any errors (just type in `pdftk one.pdf two.pdf cat output result.pdf`).
EDIT: Pro comes with PDFtk Server.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the input. I am able to combine two pdf files when I typed the file names in the batch file. I will research more. Thank you! example: pdftk A=845502.pdf B=845502-index.pdf cat B A output C:\export\done\845502.pdf

Comment: @EunNamkung See my edited answer. That should work now.

Comment: Ooops.. It's working... I forgot ) at the bottom of the script....

Comment: Hi @regejok, are you still there? I have a situation that I need to merge files again by file names. Now, I have files in one folder like this - A1.pdf, A2.pdf, B1.pdf, C1.pdf, C2.pdf, C3.pdf. The goal is to merge files by file names and I will get A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf. I tried different things in the batch file, but none worked so far. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example as below. When I execute this, I, at least get the following message. So I think I only need to tweak the script below for correct file names.

---

1. Error message when executing this batch file

   ---

File Not Found
Done. Input errors, so no output created

---

2. Where files are saved and file names

   ---

c:\merge
merge.bat (this file contains the code example below)
845499.pdf
845499-index.pdf
845502.pdf
845502-index.pdf

---

3. pdftk set up

   ---

I installed pdftk pro, and it shows when I do "PATH" in command line, and I also copied pdftk.exe in c:\merge AND c:\windows\system32

---

4. code example

   ---

   @echo off
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   rem Initialize (delete) "lastFile" and "fileList" variables
   set "lastFile="
   set "fileList="

   rem Next line get the output of a "dir /B" command, that show file names *only*
   rem "for /F" command execute the dir, get the output and divide each line in two "tokens" ("%%a" and "%%b")
   rem with the first part before the "*" in "%%a" and the *rest* (including further "*") in "%%b"

   for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *_KM_*.*') do (

   rem If the base file name changed...
      if "%%a" neq "!lastFile!" (

   ```
     rem Process previous file list;
     rem this "if" is just to avoid process the empty list the first time
     if defined fileList (
        pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
     )

     rem Reinitialize the new list
     set "lastFile=%%a"
     set "fileList=%%a_%%b"
   ```

   ) else (

   ```
     rem Append this file to current list
     set "fileList=!fileList! %%a_%%b"
   ```

   )

   )

   rem Process the last list
   pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf